# problema en carga de componentes angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

tengo un pequeño problema, tengo un carrusel de películas y cuando lo tengo con las películas en html directamente me carga correctamente, pero cuando intento hacer la peticion a mi backend para obtener la lista de mis películas y luego ejecuto un for para mostrarlas dentro del mismo solo me muestra la primera aunque la realmente tengo mas y parece que se descoloca, posiblemente deba de cargar el html y luego el .js de carrusel por lo que al hacer la petición tarda mas en obtener el html que va dentro del carrusel que en ejecutar el .js por lo que el html que se agrega posteriormente no se acopla bien (es lo que he pensado que puede estar pasando). ¿hay alguna forma de que no carge el html y .js que necesita el carrusel asta que obtenga los datos de la petición al back?

no se me ocurre otra solución.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: el diseño es descargado y los css y js estan importados en el index.html ya que al agregarlos en los imports de angular me dan errores

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticulosServiceService } from '../../services/articulos-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _articulos:ArticulosServiceService) { }
  public articulos:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.agregados_recientemente();

  }

  agregados_recientemente(){
    this._articulos.listado().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.articulos = data;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

```html
  <section class="panel">
    <h2>Añadidos Recientemente</h2>
    <div class="recentslider">
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div *ngFor="let art of articulos" class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/9.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">{{art.titulo}}</h3></a></div>
          <!-- <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/2.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">John Wick</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/3.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Spider-Man Homecoming</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/4.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Beauty and the Beast</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/5.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/6.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Fifty Shades Darker</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/7.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Transformers: The Last Knight</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/8.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">xXx: Return of Xander Cage</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/9.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Space Betwen Us</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/2.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">John Wick</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/3.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Spider-Man Homecoming</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/4.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Beauty and the Beast</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/5.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/6.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Fifty Shades Darker</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/7.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">Transformers: The Last Knight</h3></a></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="single.html"><img src="assets/images/8.jpg"><h3 class="hometitle">xXx: Return of Xander Cage</h3></a></div> -->

          <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="mostwatched.html"><img src="assets/img/others.png"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nextdirection recent-next"><img src="assets/img/right-arrow.svg"> </div>
        <div class="leftdirection recent-prev"><img src="assets/img/left-arrow.svg"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Saludos.Se necesita el código que participa en el proceso que mencionas; las imagenes sirven de apoyo para guia de lo recibido y compararlo con lo esperado.

Comment: gracias, ya esta editado

Comment: Que versión de Angular estas usando? o estas usando AngularJS?

Comment: estoy utilizando angular 9.1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema de posicionamiento del `*ngfor` deberia ir en el `<div class="swiper-wrapper">` o bien crear un div padre:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div *ngFor="let art of articulos"><!-- div padre que realiza el ciclo-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="single.html">
                <img src="assets/images/9.jpg">
                <h3 class="hometitle">{{art.titulo}}</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto es para que el contenido del div del ciclo se muestre correctamente y puedas visualizar las imágenes como deseas.